# nextjs sitemap error. type error: can not assign to read only property "undefined" of object "#<Object>"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sitemap

> hi everyone ! i am stuck with an error. ı implemented sitemap.xml.js
> fıle in page folder. It is working in dev server but don't work in
> production. using vercel hosting. Can you help?

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { API_URL } from "../lib/services"

const sitemapXML = data => {

  let projectsXML = "";
  let comUrlsXml = "";
  data.map(post => {
    const projectURL = https://example/${post.cSlug}/${post.pSlug};
    projectsXML += `
      <url>
        <loc>${projectURL}</loc>
        <priority>0.50</priority>
      </url>`;
  });

  data.map(post => {
    const comUrls = https://example/t/${post.cSlug};
    comUrlsXml += `
      <url>
        <loc>${comUrls}</loc>
        <priority>0.50</priority>
      </url>`;
  });


  return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
      ${projectsXML}
      ${comUrlsXml}
    </urlset>`;
};

class Sitemap extends React.Component {

}

export async function getServerSideProps({ res }) {
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
  const data = await axios
    .get(`${API_URL}/post/get-slugs`)
    .then(response => response.data);

  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
  res.write(sitemapXML(data));
  res.end();
  return { props: { data } }
}

export default Sitemap;
```

i get error only prodcution

[image]

Comment: It looks like your image was not placed. Could you please add the image?

Comment: please check again

Comment: Ah. Whenever you have an error, please copy paste the exact text of the error. That makes it easier for other users to find.